# Do all mathematical fields require an algebra?

Tags: soft-question, foundations

My understanding is that "algebra" refers to a specific field in mathematics. Here is Wikipedia's introduction:

> Algebra is one of the broad parts of mathematics, together with number
>   theory, geometry and analysis. In its most general form algebra is the
>   study of symbols and the rules for manipulating symbols.

With an article, e.g. "an algebra", it refers to a specific set of symbols and rules, e.g. boolean algebra.

Do some fields of mathematics **not** use an algebra? Another way of asking it is: does all mathematics involve the study of symbols and rules for manipulating symbols? If some fields do not use algebra, can I have an example? And if all fields **do** use an algebra, why is it not viewed as **the** fundamental field upon which all other fields are based?

Comment: Studying symbols and rules for manipulating symbols is pretty close to the *definition* of mathematics...

Comment: I would say that a general rule of thumb is that algebra is defined by equations (not other kinds of relations). Some mathematics is not defined by equational theories.

Comment: As soon we denote mathematical objects by symbols and somehow we present the relations between the objects, it is already algebra, I guess.

Comment: Some of the greek maths on geometry did not use algebra.

Comment: @mvw, do you know which book of euclid proves $(a-b)^2 + (a+b)^2 = 4ab$ and things like that? i know it is there but i can't remember the book it is in.

Comment: Other parts of mathematics involve the application of rules for manipulating symbols in order to study certain aspects of mathematics, but algebra involves the study of rules and in that sense is less mathematical and more metamathematical.

Comment: @abel No idea, maybe check [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_Elements) article.

Comment: @abel [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_algebra#cite_note-Greek_Geometric_Algebra-12) footnote is interesting, Euclid seems to have used a "geometric algebra". The author contrasts it to our "symbolic algebra".

Comment: @mvw, ancients used algebra but without all the symbols we are now so familiar with; introduction of the symbols into algebra is usually credited to viete.